# Format Word text

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to insert text to a Word document in a particular location using the following code:

```
selection.Font.Name = "Bold";
selection.TypeText("inserted text");
```

Well, the text is inserted in Normal format.
What's wrong?

Comment: I doubt that you want Font.Name.  Have you tried [Font.Bold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are changing Font.Name to "Bold" which doesn't exist as a font name. I think it should be selection.Font.Bold = 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is this -

```
Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.TypeText ("inserted text")
```

The font name is not "bold" but you want Bold text. Can you try this code and post if it works?

Comment: Thanks a lot! `Selection.Font.Bold ` has to get 1 instead of true- according to my trial.